# How to print String data as a table in java GUI

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, jtable

I am going to create a table in java GUI and I have found below example:

```
String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                            "Last Name",
                            "Sport",
                            "# of Years",
                            "Vegetarian"};

    Object[][] rows = {
    {"Kathy", "Smith",
     "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
    {"John", "Doe",
     "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Sue", "Black",
     "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
    {"Jane", "White",
     "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Joe", "Brown",
     "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };

    final JTable table = new JTable(rows, columnNames);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

this is simple Jtable in GUI and It shows how to add columns and rows with all set values, but what I would like to do is to print  values of collumnNames and each row automatically.
for example I have

```
String[] columnNames = {"N1","N2","N3","N4"};
Object[][] rows = {{"1", "2","3", "4"},{"5", "6","7", "8"},
```

All the values in columnNames and rows should be printed to table automatically.Because these values in columnsNames and rows are stored in two different arrays in the previous programs, I used a for loop and attempt to pass the values of the arrays to the table. Array1 stores "N1...N4", array2 stores"1 to 8". And for the value of rows, they should be added to the table one by one rather than row by row.
Is there any way to do this please help.

Comment: Any example or try you have done so far?

Comment: Print? Where? Standard output?

Comment: @araknoid I have edited the question, I　can just print the first columns with the first data in all the rows. it's looks confused. But what I want to know is how to print data from left to right( from 1 to 4) rather than typed the data in each row.

Comment: @PaulVargas Print data to the GUI Jtable

Comment: Question doesn't make sense. You talk about printing in loops but your code contains no loops. Loops are generally not used when displaying data in `JTable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically add rows of data then don't use an array for the data. Instead use the DefaultTableModel. The code would be something like:

```
String[] columnNames = {"N1","N2","N3","N4"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnName, 0);
JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Then when you want to add rows of data you can do:

```
model.addRow( new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4"} );
```

Edit:

> how to exactly add each data in each row one by one rather than add a entire row with all four values?

That is not the way a table works. A table is row based. You can add an empty row if you want.

```
model.setRowCount( model.getRowCount() + 1 );
```

Then you can update a cell individually using:

```
model.setValueAt("???", row, column);
```

But is up to you to manage the model to make sure the cell you want to update already exists in the model. You can't just add one cell at a time.

Then you can update individual

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how to exactly add each data in each row one by one rather than add a entire row with all four values?

Comment: you don't have tested your code. It doesn't compile. Use columnNames instead of columnName

Comment: @G_G, Seriously, a down vote for a typo? Don't forget to check my spelling in all my postings. I'm sure I have made one or two spelling mistakes as well. I stated the code was not tested. The idea of the code was to point the OP in the right direction. The OP obviously understood.

Comment: A typo on a piece of code means you didn't tried your solution. I dont care about typos  on normal english text

Comment: @G_G, do you really understand the point of the forum? We are here to point the OP in the right direction. We do NOT need to write a program to test every suggestion we make. The forum is NOT a code factory. We do NOT get paid for writing code. I have answered thousands of questions and have had thousands of answers accepted, so I think I understand what is necessary to have an answer accepted. As I already stated, the OP understood the suggestion and was able to implement the suggestion.